# Convert specific value in a form to avoid 1.0 does not equal 1

Tags: javascript, forms

I am currently trying to take all changes made to a form and put it into a JSON. If there are no changes than the JSON is empty. The form contains values that are strings, ints, and floats. So, I cannot cast them all as a specific type.

This wasn't an issue until I ran into the result form the console.log statement `batchsize:string 1.0 does not equal string 1`. Obviously this is correct in saying the two strings are not equal, but I am having trouble with finding a way that allows me to compare them without this being an issue. Does anyone have any advice

```
function getChanges()
{
//Get All User made changes form the website
var returnJSON = "{ ";
$('#form *').filter(' input:not([type="submit"])').each(function(){
    var current = this.value;
    var original = this.getAttribute('value')
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if((id!=="prod")&&(id!=="prodamt")&&(id!=="subtotal")&&(id!=="matlamt")&&(id!=="tax")&&(id!=="total")&&(id!=="matl")&&(id!=="prod-detail-formula-price")&&(id!=="prod-detail-formula-taxable")) //this ones for you zoe
        if(current !== original)
        {   
            returnJSON += '"'+id+'" : { "original":"'+original+'", "modified":"'+current+'"},';
            console.log(id+":"+typeof original+ original +" does not equal " +typeof current+current);
        }   
});
returnJSON = returnJSON.substr(0, returnJSON.length-1);
returnJSON += '}';
return returnJSON;
}
```

Comment: Are you comparing results only during submit?

Comment: @EdwinDijasChiwona Correct, it does a comparison before being submitted to be saved to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$.isNumeric()` and if both are numeric check are they equal as a numbers using `parseFloat` or `parseInt` to convert to numeric

Comment: This worked perfectly, here is what I had.
`if($.isNumeric(current)&&$.isNumeric(original))
  {
   current = parseFloat(current);
   original = parseFloat(original);
  }
`